# C# when stopping a FOR loop, it counts rest of the numbers as 0

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, count

I'm writing program for my class homework, and I'm stuck.
The program asks how many numbers you will write, then when you're done it counts the odd and even from the array (I mean the`int[] i` <- where i[1] i[2] etc.). But it also has to have a "stop" function - when you write stop it should stop and finish its job - but the problem is when I'm making a for example 120 numbers table, when I stop it on the 8th number, it counts the numbers from 9-120 as "0" and it says it's an even number. How can I repair it?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication10
    {
       class Program
       {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

              int sum1 = 0, 
              sum2 = 0; 

            start: 
            Console.WriteLine("How many numbers?"); 
            string lenght = Console.ReadLine(); 
            int Arraylenght = 0;
            bool test = int.TryParse(lenght, out Arraylenght); 
            if (test == false) 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("\n>> Error!\n"); 
                goto start; 
            }
            int[] Numbers = new int[Arraylenght]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < Arraylenght; i++) 
            { 

            start2: 
                Console.WriteLine("Enter number #{0}:", i + 1); 
                String UserInput = Console.ReadLine(); 
                bool test2 = int.TryParse(UserInput, out Numbers[i]); 
                if (test2 == false && UserInput != "stop") 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n>> Error!\n"); 
                    goto start2; 
                } 
                if (UserInput == "stop")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n>> Stopped!\n");
                    Arraylenght = i;
                }
            } 
            foreach (int number in Numbers) 
            {
                if (number % 2 == 0) sum1 = sum1 + 1; 
                if (number % 2 != 0) sum2 = sum2 + 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum1 + " even numbers" + " \n" + sum2 + " odd  numbers" ); 
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its an `array` not a table... but for stopping.. do you mean you ask the  user for input every iteration in the loop or do you use threads? Also, what level of school is this? because `goto` is bad practice but might be ok..

Comment: It's the basic of the basics. It's a homework of my girlfriend, and I've never been programming in c# but I'm trying to help her. This is a code their made in their class.
There is checking if i < numbers of numbers you declared on start (Arraylenght) 
and then a stopping with i = Arraylenght so it stops asking for the next numbers and prints the odd and even numbers count

Comment: You should also really avoid the use of Goto's in your code.  They are very rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foreach does not stop your new ArrayLength, ıt stops its end of array. So you should not use foreach you should use for. That means; 
You should use this:

```
   for(int x =0; x<=Arraylenght;x++)
   {
      if (Numbers[x] % 2 == 0) sum1 = sum1 + 1; 
      if (Numbers[x] % 2 != 0) sum2 = sum2 + 1;
   }
   Console.WriteLine(sum1 + " even numbers" + " \n" + sum2 + " odd  numbers" );
```

instead of

```
    foreach (int number in Numbers) 
    {
        if (number % 2 == 0) sum1 = sum1 + 1; 
        if (number % 2 != 0) sum2 = sum2 + 1;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sum1 + " even numbers" + " \n" + sum2 + " odd  numbers" );
```

Comment: If it works you can say it is yours answer of question.

Comment: Oh okay, also tried to give a rep, but looks like stackoverflow doesn't wan't noobies to add reputation, but thanks aswell!

Comment: No problem. Also I edit my answer because there is a mistake.

Comment: Yeah but I've changed it at once so it wasn't actually a problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When initialising the array, every item is set to 0, so you get `0 % 2 == 0` which evaluates to true. You now have two options: Either you only read the numbers to display until you reach the specified stopping point, or you use a `List<int>` which is basically a strongly typed dynamic array. 
EDIT: 
You can also make it an array of nullable ints, which makes it possible for any value of the array to represent a null value. Because `null % 2` evaluates to `null`, the only other edit you have to make is you test for an odd number at the end.